# Is it always possible to arrive at a desired item on Wikipedia starting from a random item?

Tags: complexity-theory

On Wikipedia, I tried a number of times to find the item I needed, starting from a random page and clicking on various (non-random) hyperlinks. Every time I succeeded in finding my desired item. Is this always possible?

Comment: It is possible if and only if the graph has exactly one strongly connected component. Whether or not that is the case with Wikipedia I have no idea.

Comment: Wikipedia sometimes has [dead-end pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Dead-end_pages) that contain no hyperlinks. If you get there, you are stuck.